# Hungarian notation in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, hungarian-notation

I have to do some maintenance on legacy code that uses Hungarian notation (and Systems Hungarian at that). Unfortunately, it's not practical for me to just clean it all out of the codebase.

Local Eclipse users claim that Eclipse can be configured so that auto-generated accessors and whatnot ignore the Hungarian prefixes (which is probably why they've been able to live with them for so long).

Is there any similar functionality in IDEA 10.5? It'd be nice if 'find usages' on `m_sInstruction` was smart enough to realize that `getInstruction()` is a getter, and give me the 'do you want to search for accessors?' prompt, for instance, or if 'generate getters and setters' could tell that this class already has them for almost all fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings` | `Code Style` | `Java` | `Code Generation`, set the **Name prefix** for **Field** and **Static field**.

Comment: I can see how that could get me the `m_`, but will it get me the `s` for String? (Yes, I know it's demented.)

Comment: Sorry, but it's not supported for type specific prefixes.